# Creating the array in which every element has couple of parameters

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, collections

I need to create the array/arraylist (don't know what is better in this situation) in which every element of the array will have 3 parameters.
it must be an array of songs(elements) and each song must have these 3 parameters(title, name, duration). later I will need to count all the durations of each song.

In the `addSong` method, I wanted to create the array that gonna be 1 element of the ArrayList, but it doesn't work properly. Thanks for help.

```
public class Jukebox extends Song {
    public ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public void addSong() throws IOException {
        String[] array = new String[3];

        System.out.println("Composer:");
        array[0] = reader.readLine();

        System.out.println("Title");
        array[1] = reader.readLine();

        System.out.println("Duration");
        array[2] = reader.readLine();

        ArrayList<String>songs = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
        this.songs = songs;

        //Song newSong = new Song();
        //System.out.println("Composer: ");
        //newSong.composer = reader.readLine();

        //System.out.println(" Title: ");
        //newSong.title=reader.readLine();

        //System.out.println(" Duration: ");
        //newSong.duration = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());

        //songs.add(newSong);

    }

    public void playAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
            int j = songs.size() - i - 1;
            System.out.print(songs.get(j) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I have already created the class Song, I just didn't add it here.

```
class Song {
    String composer;
    String title;
    double duration;

    public String getComposer() {
        return composer;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public double getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + composer + duration ;
    }
}
```

Comment: `...it must be an array of songs(elements) and each song must have these 3 parameters(title, name, duration)` You've got your model described here pretty well. So what you need an `ArrayList<Song>` and a `Song` class that has 3 fields as you described it.

Comment: You have a **syntax error**, you are missing the closing brace at the end of `addSong()`. Technically, you have nested your `playAll()` method inside of `addSong()`. The code above, was the output after formatting your original code.

Comment: If you are always expecting those three parameters, why not create three variables, and them pass them to the constructor after they have been set/validated?

Comment: @TyLer this seems like an almost 'homework' question. If it is iit really shouldn't be here, or you should mark your question as such so as the answers will help to lead you to your solution without hand feeding it too you. I hesitate to give you a -1 as the rest of the question is clear and well formulated.

Comment: @DaveM its not a homework. i was trying to solve this problem for a couple of hours, and I couldnnt. what u would do if u were me?

Comment: @TyLeR you should make a note of this in your question. As I was going to +1 you but wasn't sure if it was homework or not. Are you following a tutorial or book from somewhere?

Comment: @DaveM my friend gave me this task for practising.

Comment: @TyLeR well taking it to the next step I would suggest going for a hash map, and overriding comparable for your object to enable them to be sorted in various orders (composer, title etc). After that go on to implement the same via a dB with a GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Song` class.

```
public class Song{
  String composer, title;
  int duration;
  public Song(String composer, String title, int duration){
    this.composer = composer;
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;
   }
 // getter & setters
}
```

Create a `Song` object for every single Song

```
    System.out.println("Composer:");
    String composer = reader.readLine();

    System.out.println("Title");
    String title = reader.readLine();

    System.out.println("Duration");
    int duration = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    Song song = new Song(composer,title,duration);
```

Add everything into a `List<Song>`

```
//create a `ArrayList` before
List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
// add songs
songs.add(song)
```

---

To get all the duration

```
int totalDuration = 0;
for(Song s : songs){
  totalDuration += s.getDuration();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you make a Song class that will have this three fields and store it in an List?

Comment: It appears that Tyler has already begun to do that, it's just that the code is commented out.

Comment: I've added the class Song with variables.

Answer (score 0):

You would wanna create a Song class with 3 fields and add the Song instances to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Song class

```
public class Song{
  private String composer;
  private String title;
  private String duration; //you can even take it as Int
  //write the codes for getters and setters over here
}
```

Then define a List:

```
List<Song> songs=new ArrayList<Song>();
```